# Question about discrete-to-digital IC's output current

Tags: digital-logic, datasheet

I am designing in a discrete-to-digital converter in my project ([link](http://www.deiaz.com/data-sheets/DS-MW-01026-01-D.pdf))

and I am confused about the device's output current capabilities. I would like to know the maximum value so I can make sure I don't overdrive the LEDs that will be connected to the outputs.

Here is a capture of the screen shot that talks about the output sourcing.
[image]

My question is why does it have Ioh labeled as a minimum value and nothing for max? I was expecting it to provide a max value. Do they call it a minimum value because of the conventional current negative sign, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: That is showing the maximum you should make it source OR sink is 5mA... What you actually take will depend on what your load is. It is not current limited at 5mA.

Comment: I think its the maximum value only. given in minimum value column just because of the negative sign

Comment: Ok thanks. Its a bit confusing since its in the 'MIN' column but this clears things up.